# Turn off OS X AppNap with install4j

Tags: install4j, osx-mavericks

After the OS X Mavericks update my agent / daemon goes to sleep after a couple of minutes and stops reacting to user actions. How can I disable the AppNap during installation?

It's a Java application, and I'm using install4j. I read somewhere that I should add an entry in this list

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist
```

However, that list doesn't exist on my Macbook even after manually disabled AppNap for the application. The setting must be stored somewhere else.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Add the following entry to the Info.plist (Modify Launcher -> executable info -> Mac OS X Info.plist file):

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: LSUIElement indicates the application is an agent that should not appear in the dock. What if you still want the application to appear in the dock? I can't find any other way to disable App Nap but I see that intellij has done it somehow - looks like it has custom native launchers.